# How to use min and max range on pre-release development Python packages in requirements.txt

Tags: python, pip, requirements.txt

```
abc.servicebus >= 1.0.0b1943.*, <1.0.0b1944
```

I am using pre-release development servicebus library in `requirements.txt` file at a Python project.

There are other `abc.servicebus` libraries with a higher pre-release number such as `1.0.0b2414.dev1`

When I use just `abc.servicebus >= 1.0.0b1943.*`, `abc.servicebus` library from `b2414` would be installed.

I need to get the latest `abc.servicebus` from `b1943`, not from `b2414`.
For example: I want to install:

- 1.0.0b1943.dev14+0c6e487
- 1.0.0b1943.dev15+796f5da

When I use `abc.servicebus >= 1.0.0b1943.*, <1.0.0b1944`, the pip install would fail.

How to install the latest pre-release development library & exclude other version as well?

Comment: Why not just `abc.servicebus >= 1.0.0b1943, <1.0.0b1944` ?

Comment: @phd, I tried using `pip install abc.servicebus ">= 1.0.0b1943, <1.0.0b1944"`, but I got error message saying >ERROR: No matching distribution found...